# How to add parameter to command inside an Interaction tag

Tags: wpf, command

I would like to use the content of the button as a parameter for my command, but I am getting this message: `The property 'Content' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction'` I was thinking to bind the content property of my button to my ViewModel and use the value in my ViewModel(note I have 10 other buttons using the same functionality) is it recommended to use the ViewModel for the content or is there a way of using the XAML to Get the content of my button.

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Height="30">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}"   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=button}"
```